# Google Pay via NFC rejects SELECT PPSE(2PAY.SYS.DDF01)

Tags: nfc, kiosk, google-pay

I'm programming kiosk application to accept contactless payments via [device](https://szhcct.en.made-in-china.com/product/tjQnlTWKIpcf/China-4-in-1-All-in-One-Card-Reader-USB-Mobile-E-Payment-POS-Security-Pinpad-Z90PD-.html) with NFC reader.

So far I achieved success with a number of Visa and Mastercard cards, and with Apple Pay.
But with Google Pay it fails on sending SELECT PPSE(2PAY.SYS.DDF01) APDU (device API function ExcangeAPDU() returns undocumented error number).

Does Google Pay support this command, or I should use something else to communicate with it? Or may be it requires some tricky initialization?